# Finding discrepancies in distances between random variable samples

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, distance-covariance

There are $N$ independent and unknown points $p_i$, $q_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $i \in [1, N]$. I want to find if the pairwise squared Euclidean distance of each $i$ pair is the same for all of them, or if any of them is significatively different. It is to say, is $\|p_i - q_i\|^2_2$ always the same, with some small margin of error?

I cannot observe any $p_i$, $q_i$ points, just a single estimate of them (denoted $\bar{p}_i$ and $\bar{q}_i$) that I assume are drawn from normal distributions: $P_i \sim \mathcal{N}(p_i, \Sigma_{p_i})$ and $Q_i \sim \mathcal{N}(q_i, \Sigma_{q_i})$. The covariances are known.

I can model the difference of each observation with a normal distribution $D_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{p}_i - \bar{q}_i, \Sigma_{p_i} + \Sigma_{q_i})$. I am not very sure how I can go from here.

The squared distance should be given by $D_i^t D_i$. I think it is the distribution 
$$ (\bar{p}_i - \bar{q}_i)^t (\Sigma_{p_i} + \Sigma_{q_i})^{-1}(\bar{p}_i - \bar{q}_i) \sim \chi^2_3.$$
Is this correct?

If it is, then I have $N$ values drawn from $\chi^2_3$. Can I do a $\chi^2$-test on them to find if all of them agree for some probability?